# How to fix RuntimeException: error reading Scala signature of com.snp.utils.DbUtils: error reading Scala signature

Tags: scala, apache-spark, datastax, cassandra-2.0

I have defined

```
var status:String = null;
var error_msg:String = null;
try{ status ="Error";  error_msg= "n/a";
 }
```

When I place my method in DbUtils object and call from my main class it is throwing error, i.e. when calling

```
 DbUtils.writeToCassandraAuditLog(spark, status, error_msg);
```

it throws below error

```
 2018-10-23 14:03:37 ERROR java.lang.RuntimeException: error reading Scala signature of com.snp.utils.DbUtils: error reading Scala signature of org.apache.spark.sql.package: assertion failed: unsafe symbol Unstable (child of <none>) in runtime reflection universe
 at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler.unpickle(UnPickler.scala:46)
```

But when I place/define the methods in my main class/object it is working fine.

```
 writeToCassandraAuditLog(spark, status, error_msg);
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: @Alexott sir any clue what am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: did you find out how to get this fixed